# How to use an async closure both capturing and accepting references

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures, lifetime

I am trying to pass a closure returning `Future<Output=bool>` to an async function and call this closure as an async predicate (something like an async `.filter` or other higher-order function).

This predicate receives its input as a reference. I found how to implement it for pure predicates that do not capture their environment:

```rust
type BoxFuture<'a, Out> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Out> + 'a + Send>>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 1 -> Closure only uses the inner argument                                  //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// Run the computation and check that its output is not empty
fn run1<'a>(expected: &'a [u8]) -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a {
  async move {
    let is_ok = compute_and_check1(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
      b.len() > 0 // Only uses the inner argument
    }));
    let is_ok1 = is_ok.await;
    dbg!(is_ok1);
  }
}

/// Compute some bytes (may be complex / use async), then check their validity
/// with a user-supplied function, finally do some clean-up and return.
async fn compute_and_check1<F>(check: F) -> bool
  where
    F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r [u8]) -> BoxFuture<'r, bool>
{
  let bytes = [0u8; 128];
  let is_ok = check(&bytes).await;
  drop(bytes);
  is_ok
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d25aab628a78cff8d9943c29831a79d)

Supporting only non-capturing closures is quite limiting. I would like to use a closure that captures its environment. By changing the bounds of my `compute_and_check` function, I am able to pass a closure that uses its environment - but not its input:

```rust
type BoxFuture<'a, Out> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Out> + 'a + Send>>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 2 -> Closure only uses the outer argument                                  //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// Run the computation and assume that its output is not empty if `expected` is not empty
fn run2<'a>(expected: &'a [u8]) -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a {
  async move {
    let is_ok = compute_and_check2(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
      expected.len() > 0 // Only uses the environment
    }));
    let is_ok2 = is_ok.await;
    dbg!(is_ok2);
  }
}

/// Compute some bytes (may be complex / use async), then check their validity
/// with a user-supplied function, finally do some clean-up and return.
async fn compute_and_check2<'a, F>(check: F) -> bool
  where
    F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r [u8]) -> BoxFuture<'a, bool>
{
  let bytes = [0u8; 128];
  let is_ok = check(&bytes).await;
  drop(bytes);
  is_ok
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=451861e5ea137507945fe5e8d13937e1)

I can write an implementation where the closure uses its input, and one where the closure uses its environment. But not both at the same time.

**How can I accept a Future-producing closure that uses references for both its input and environment?**

What I would like to write is something like this:

```rust
type BoxFuture<'a, Out> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Out> + 'a + Send>>;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 3 -> Closure uses both the inner and outer arguments                       //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// Run the computation and check its output is the provided expected value
fn run3<'a>(expected: &'a [u8]) -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a {
  async move {
    let is_ok = compute_and_check3(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
      b == expected // Uses both the input and environment
    }));
    let is_ok2 = is_ok.await;
    dbg!(is_ok2);
  }
}

/// Compute some bytes (may be complex / use async), then check their validity
/// with a user-supplied function, finally do some clean-up and return.
async fn compute_and_check3<'a, F>(check: F) -> bool
  where
    F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r [u8]) -> BoxFuture<'r + 'a, bool>
{
  let bytes = [0u8; 128];
  let is_ok = check(&bytes).await;
  drop(bytes);
  is_ok
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3db9d017059fbbf2c4f2607135dc898d)

This code does not compile because I am asking the closure to return `BoxFuture<'r + 'a, bool>` but this is not legal syntax:

```
error[E0226]: only a single explicit lifetime bound is permitted
  --> src/main.rs:89:51
   |
89 |     F: for<'r> FnOnce(&'r [u8]) -> BoxFuture<'r + 'a, bool>
   |                                                   ^^
```

From what I understand, the core of my issue is that I need to restrict my Higher-Ranked Trait Bound. Instead of "for any `'r`", I want to say "for any `'r` that does not outlive `'a`" but I don't see how to write it down.

I tried to use two lifetimes and restrictions to my `BoxFuture` type alias, or define an auxilliary trait but I did not manage to solve this issue because I fail to apply restrictions on the HRTB lifetime.

For completness, here are the errors I get when passing my final closure to `compute_and_check1` (only input) and `compute_and_check2` (only environment):

- [Using `compute_and_check1` (only input) playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc58cf700e739d5414cd669097c0d903)

  ```
  error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
    --> src/main.rs:17:67
     |
  17 |       let is_ok = compute_and_check1(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
     |  ___________________________________________________________________^
  18 | |       b == expected
  19 | |     }));
     | |_____^
     |
  note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 15:9...
    --> src/main.rs:15:9
     |
  15 | fn run3<'a>(expected: &'a [u8]) -> impl Future<Output=()> + 'a {
     |         ^^
  note: ...so that the types are compatible
    --> src/main.rs:17:67
     |
  17 |       let is_ok = compute_and_check1(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
     |  ___________________________________________________________________^
  18 | |       b == expected
  19 | |     }));
     | |_____^
     = note: expected `(&[u8], &[u8])`
                found `(&[u8], &'a [u8])`
  note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 17:36...
    --> src/main.rs:17:36
     |
  17 |       let is_ok = compute_and_check1(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
     |  ____________________________________^
  18 | |       b == expected
  19 | |     }));
     | |______^
  note: ...so that the expression is assignable
    --> src/main.rs:17:47
     |
  17 |       let is_ok = compute_and_check1(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
     |  _______________________________________________^
  18 | |       b == expected
  19 | |     }));
     | |______^
     = note: expected `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool> + Send>>`
                found `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = bool> + Send>>`
  ```
- [Using `compute_and_check2` (only environment) playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=790c5144643259bffd588a3d92641cc0)

  ```
  error: lifetime may not live long enough
    --> src/main.rs:17:47
     |
  17 |       let is_ok = compute_and_check2(|b: &[u8]| Box::pin(async move {
     |  ________________________________________-____-_^
     | |                                        |    |
     | |                                        |    return type of closure is Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = bool> + Send + '2)>>
     | |                                        let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
  18 | |       b == expected
  19 | |     }));
     | |______^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  ```

I have also looked into [the `unboxed_closure` nightly feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/unboxed-closures.html) but did not manage to solve my issue. I would prefer my code to work on stable Rust but it is acceptable for my code to require nightly if it is the only solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can make this work without using a "scoped" runtime. There's [`tokio-scoped`](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-scoped), but I have never used it and it doesn't look to be much used, so I wouldn't be too optimistic.

Comment: You can do much the same using reference counting though: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f33c52aab9ba6dd9c2c103177c47c7ca

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The root cause of my problem is that I actually wanted something like `tokio-scoped` but this library is unmaintained. Structured concurrency in general is a hard problem for Tokio. Regarding using `Arc`, it works by making the environment `'static`: in this case its fine, but it remains a workaround that requires introducing reference-counting where it is otherwise not needed.